# If statements suddenly get formatted on next line by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting

Hello suddenly VS2010 has started formatting my if statements in a way that I don't want and I don't know how to turn it of..I Used to format if statements without accolades like this.

```
if (true) DoThis();
```

But now VS2010 formats that as follows all the time.

```
if (true)
    DoThis();
```

I Don't want this and it drives me nuts. 
I Don't have any plugins installed.
Can anybody help me ? Where I can adjust this setting ?

Comment: Check in the options that "Text editors"-->"C#"-->"Formatting"-->"Wrapping"-->"Leave block on single line" is checked

Comment: For what its worth, I find it much easier to debug when code is laid out in the 'new' verbose way, since it is easier to work with breakpoints...

Comment: Fergus, you can right click+addbreakpoint on "dothis()"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was

> options->text editor->c#->Wrapping->Leave statements and member
>   declarations on same line.

(must be turned on).

Steve B you can have the Kudus because you directed me to "almost" the right option.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# (or whatever language you're using) > Formatting > New Lines.  See what you have selected in there.

Also, you mentioned you didn't have any plug-ins, but do you have Reshaper installed?  I know of resharper settings that are specifically designed to format if-blocks.

Edit: @Steve B was correct, instead of "New Lines", select "Wrapping" and select "Leave Block on single line"